# iLO Integrated Remote Console stuck

Tags: hp-proliant

Currently when i try to use the Remote Console on from my iLO4 ProLiant DL380 Gen9 server I get the pop-up where the console opens however I am unable to see the login user/password prompt or anything.

Note that there are no network issues & this issue can be resolved by restarting the server as it has happened a couple of times before. Also I can see the RHEL logo (RHEL 7.2) and everything on the Remote Console but that's how far it goes.

I am interesting in finding a way I can restart the iLO Remote GUI only instead of restarting the whole server as it is a real pain to close all the services and restart.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just resetting the iLO as opposed to rebooting the entire server? The reset iLO option is in the diagnostics menu of the iLO.

Comment: @fvu Yes actually I already tried reset iLO option but it didn't help at all. The situation in remote console was still the same.

Comment: Voting to move to ServerFault.  Likely more users with iLO experience there

Comment: @DaveM How do i vote ? Or you mean i go and open another question there ?

Comment: Once you have enough reputation, you chick UP and DOWN arrows next to question.  Take the tour for details https://superuser.com/tour

Comment: Do you have physical access to the console? If you do, check if the server responds to physical keyboard when you have this issue again. I strongly believe you have some console or USB driver issue in the OS, not an iLO problem, as otherwise it would be sorted out by iLO restart. Also, if you could login remotely over SSH, seeing a `dmesg` output when the problem has occurred would help.

Comment: @PeterZhabin I don't have physical access to the console. The thing is when I try to login the remote console all options eg. change font/zoom in etc on the login screen work but I cant see the login user/password option. The middle part is just background colour. Meanwhile I just restarted the server over the weekend and everything is fine now but i really need to find an alternative solution. Is there any way I can restart the Remote console GUI only from putty?. Does ILO & ILO remote console both reset while we reset the ILO ?

Comment: So you actually have your mouse/keyboard working on login screen? Can you actually click on anything there and see the result, and you just don't have login/password window? And were talking about X window, right?

Comment: @PeterZhabin Sorry i am not aware of what is X window. I was able to use the mouse/keyboard over the iLO remote console. Its just that where we have the user name & the textbox to type the password, nothing was there. Something like this constantly keeps happening with the iLO remote console where mouse is moving around but the screen is blank/ showing nothing etc. A restart of the server will fix the issue but I cannot keep restarting hence I wanted to find a way to just restart the iLO remote console.

Comment: This is not an issue with iLO. This is an issue with gdm, or whatever display manager you're using, as thats the component responsible for providing a login window. There also could be an interference with some vnc/teamviewer sessions if they are used. Next time this situation occurs, login via ssh and issue `systemctl restart gdm.service` and see if it helps

Comment: @PeterZhabin Thank you !! Let me try it next time. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue with iLO. This is an issue with gdm, or whatever display manager you're using, as thats the component responsible for providing a login window. There also could be an interference with some vnc/teamviewer sessions if they are used. Next time this situation occurs, login via ssh and issue `systemctl restart gdm.service` and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, I faced the same issue again and unfortunately the restart `gdm.service` didn't help.. I might have to restart server again tonight.